# Viewport performance, i9-9900k vs Ryzen 3970x?

Tags: 3d-view, rigid-body-simulation, performance

(Apologies in advance in case this is the wrong place to ask this!)

I'm building a new workstation and trying to decide which CPU to go with.

Does the viewport performance in Blender benefit from having a CPU with more cores (e.g. Ryzen 3960x/3970x), or would the performance still be similar to e.g. an Intel i9-9900k with less cores but slightly better single core speed? And what about playback/baking speeds for e.g. simulations, would more cores be faster for that stuff?

I use the GPU for rendering 99% of the time, so I'm not too worried about the CPU difference for rendering.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about Blender, but about computer hardware.

Comment: Sorry for the off-topic question, Martynas! Do you know any other good forum I could ask for help regarding this question? Thanks!

Comment: Single thread performance is what you are after if it's a workstation. You will feel the difference at those times when only one core is used and there are still plenty of those while modelling or in simulations. For rendering, the more cores the better. I would go for less cores, more powerful single thread performance myself if I had a separate rendering solution in mind.

Comment: Blenderartists.org is usually a good place for questions that do not fully fit here.

Comment: Okay, sounds good! I'll probably look at one with a more powerful single thread performance then. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is a quick answer A higher cor clock will help because blender is coded in almost exclusive python because python benefits form single core performance. So therefore a faster per core performance is useful.